# Vb.net Connection to 2013 password protected access database

Tags: wpf, vb.net, ms-access

Thanks for the help in advance

I am using access 2013 with a wpf vb.net app at the moment I have

```
 Public sConnstring As String
 Function Conn_DB1()
    '<<<<<<<<<<<<<< This is for Data Base 1 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    sConnstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= " & My.Settings.DatastoreLocation & "\ACCDB\DB1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"
    Return sConnstring
  End Function
```

However as I want to password protect the database if I use the old

```
sConnstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= " & My.Settings.DatastoreLocation & "\ACCDB\DB1.accdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

I can not seem to get it to connect I get the error

"Cannot Open Database - It may not be that the database that your application recognizes, or that the file may be corrupt"

Any Ideas as to why this may be happening?

Cheers

Comment: [This page](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/with-database-password/) at connectionstrings.com says "**Note!** Reports say that a database encrypted using Access 2010 - 2013 default encryption scheme does not work with this connection string. In Access; try options and choose 2007 encryption method instead. That should make it work. We do not know of any other solution. Please get in touch if other solutions is available!". Have you checked that?

Comment: Hello Cheers however yes I have looked into that however I cant work out a way to encrypt the database in 2007 it does not give me an option anywhere in access to change into 2007 encryption.

Comment: Hello, the link below points to a simple windows forms project that shows opening a password protected msaccess database where the connection string is hard-coded created with a connection string builder. This can be used in a wpf project also. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3D5A9A9A28080D1!261&authkey=!APXxDJGWUdafTrQ&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: Hi Karen Thanks for your response is there anyway I can get around it with just a string like above? or do I have to user a builder, its just I have developed the app and realised I need a password database however all my connection use the public sConnstring as the database conn